# Cyrillic in the android.widget.TextView

Tags: cyrillic, androidviewclient

Im using android view client to automate testing of an android app, but all of the views are on Russian, so when I'm using dump.py
i have something like this:

```
 android.widget.TextView id/no_id/16 ╨в╤А╨░╨╜╤Б╨┐╨╛╤А╤В
```

How can I see it in normal view? Because it's not comfortably to find the vies in such view.

**Update**

I used chcp 65001 and got one TextView on Russian, but after thata I recieved an error:

```
                     android.widget.TextView id/no_id/15 Все категорииTraceback
(most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\AndroidViewClient\AndroidViewClient-maste
r\AndroidViewClient\tools\dump.py", line 128, in <module>
    vc.traverse(transform=transform)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\AndroidViewClient\AndroidViewClient-maste
r\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py", line 1754, in trave
rse
    return ViewClient.__traverse(root, indent, transform, stream)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\AndroidViewClient\AndroidViewClient-maste
r\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py", line 1776, in __tra
verse
    ViewClient.__traverse(ch, indent=indent+"   ", transform=transform, stream=s
tream)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\AndroidViewClient\AndroidViewClient-maste
r\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py", line 1773, in __tra
verse
    print >>stream, ius.encode('utf-8', 'replace')
IOError: [Errno 0] Error
```

Answer (score 0):

This is obtained using latest `dump` (in tools directory) and a google Keep note with the title *Привет мир*:

```
              ...
              android.widget.RelativeLayout id/no_id/18 
                 android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/19 
                    android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/20 
                       android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/21 
                          android.widget.EditText id/no_id/22 Привет мир
                       android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/23 
                          android.widget.ImageView id/no_id/24 
                          android.widget.ImageView id/no_id/25
```

This was tested on OS X and Linux.
If you are not seeing it perhaps the problem is with your operating system ;-).